# how to resolve a problem a must be greater than 0 in dataframe?

Tags: python

**My code is:**

```
df.query('level == {0}'.format(i)).sample(nsamples).image.apply( lambda v: (os.path.join(datadir, v) + '.jpeg', i)).values.tolist()
```

**The error I've been getting:**

`ValueError: 'a' must be greater than 0 unless no samples are taken`

Comment: Does your .query return an empty dataframe?

Comment: `'a' must be greater than 0` error is thrown because some of the pandas DataFrame are empty.

Comment: you may check `length` of `sample` before process it

Comment: I had the same error at the code line `samp = np.random.choice(n_docs, samp_size)` and `n_docs` turned out to be 0, since `n_docs = len(docs)`, with docs being an empty series "shape (0,)". It was empty because I had reduced my dataset so much that in the few thousand rows that I had chosen, there had been no "abstract" in any document, though preprocess(MY_SERIES, samp_size=samp_size) expected a *non-empty* series as MY_SERIES, that is, with at least one "abstract" in that series.